# Designing an icon to fit the iOS 7 style

Tags: icon, ios, iphone

I want to create an icon for my iOS App that keys into iOS 7's new design and color scheme. What kinds of colors should I use and what key things should I implement in the design?

Comment: Is it something other than http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41002/should-apps-design-evolve-according-to-the-os-version/41009#41009 ? If you have a specific question, it would be good.

Comment: This fine work of satire might help... http://www.fastcodesign.com/1672827/jony-ive-redesigns-things-is-the-best-tumblr-this-week

Answer (score 1):

See the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](http://www.ifans.com/goto/https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH6-SW1).

Comment: Could you please quote the relevant part of the Transition guide? It's located behind a registration wall.

Comment: I think that would breach [Apple's developer agreement](https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/registered_apple_developer_20100301.pdf).  In particular, "4. Confidentiality. You agree that any Apple pre-release software ... (_including related documentation_ and materials) ... will be considered and referred to as “Apple Confidential Information”." Which is followed by "...you 
agree not to disclose, publish, or disseminate any Apple Confidential Information to anyone..."

Comment: I'm no lawyer, but I don't believe anything in the standard developer resources are confidential. Anyone can sign up for a developer AppleID.

Comment: The opening paragraph of the Transition Guide explicitly states that it is non-final, pre-release material and is considered "Apple confidential" for registered members.  You are correct that anyone can register and get access to the material, and they would still be in violation of their agreement if they post the contents here.